# To top button with return back function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make "To top" button with return back function:

1. User press button
2. Page scrolls up
3. Button does not disappear
4. If press button again, page scrolls down to position, where user press button first time (step 1).

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
  }
});
// scroll body to 0px on click
$('#back-to-top').click(function() {
  $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 800);
  return false;
});

$('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
```

```css
.back-to-top {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<br>test
<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg back-to-top" role="button" title="Click to return on the top page" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>


</div>
</div>
```

How can I return back ones?

Comment: The snippet seems to be working fine. I don't see any issues.

Comment: Working fine! no issue.

Comment: Hassan and Nawed... read once again the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will cover all this important UX cases:

- **User manually scrolls down & up**: Button disappears if scroll less than 50
- **User scrolls down and clicks "To Top"**: page animates to top and stores the last known max position. The button once clicked stays always visible.
- **User clicks "Back down"**: Page animates to the latest known *bottom position*
- **User clicks "To top" and than manually scrolls down surpassing the latest known max position**: The "Back down" button automatically renames to "To top" - behaving as expected.
- **User clicks "To top", than manually surpasses the max position and than scrolls back manually to top**: The button behaves as never clicked.
- (As said, the button automatically changes text)

Try them all:

```js
const $win = $(window);
const $toTop = $('#back-to-top');
const visibleAt = 50;
let Y = 0;
let clickY = 0;

$win.on('scroll', function() {
  Y = $win.scrollTop();
  if(clickY && Y >= clickY) clickY = 0; // In case user surpasses the clickY by manual scroll
  $toTop
    .toggleClass('is-visible', !!clickY  || Y > visibleAt)
    .text(clickY ? 'Back down' : 'To top');
});

$toTop.on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: clickY ? clickY : 0});
  clickY = Y; // Store last click position
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 400vh;
  border: 4px dashed #000;
}

#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.24s;
  background: #0bf;
  user-select: none; /* prevent "button" text highlight */
}

#back-to-top.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#top" id="back-to-top">To top</a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Additionally you should better use a `<button type="button" id="back-to-top">To top</button>` instead of a draggable anchor.